# Can Phottix Odin flash trigger work in tandem with Nikons CLS?

Tags: flash, popup-flash, wireless-flash, cls, pocket-wizard

I'm wondering whether it is possible to still use the built-in flash while using the Phottix Odin mounted (and using it) on my Nikon camera. Physically, it seems to me that since the Odin is built upright, it shouldnt be a problem popping up the built in flash. But can anyone confirm that?

My bigger worry is whether the Odin system will let the built-in flash join the game. Does it? And if it does, can I also use it in commander mode for the Creative Lighting System (CLS)? That would be fantastic since it would allow me to use the radio triggers for those flashes that are not reached by the IR connection of the CLS and continue to use CLS where possible.

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Which Nikon do you have?

Comment: It's a D600. I left this information out on purpose, cause I believe that the answer should apply to any Nikon with the Creative Lighting System.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that, the body shapes vary, though it may be true in any event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, No. I have a D600, and a set of 3 photix odins (nikon) and 3 sb600s.
The commander fits on top the D600, but the cameras built in flash only incompletely opens and will not flash with the odin on top.
The Odin commander does allow full CTS with three flash groups, and remote zooming of your flash (so it is an improvement on the Nikon inbuilt CLS with 2 flash groups as it does not rely on line of sight and allows you to zoom the flashes also) Odins also allow you to balance group a and group B to get optimal lighting ratios, also controls autofocus illumination on/off.
Not sure when you would need IR and radio separately. just get enough odin triggers to fulfill all your needs then you never have to worry about line of sight again. of course IR is cool for simple one flash set ups, so you dont have to carry all that gear all the time. Enjoy.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this now. Just received my Odin triggers and realized that, no, it doesnt work. Well, when would you need that combination? Several scenarios: Firstly, you safe money if you don't have to but an Odin reveiver for those flashes in your setup where line of sight is not a problem. Secondly, if you can use the built-in flash together with Odin, that simply gives you a third flash...

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, stuff attached to hot shoe will obstruct pop-up flash from opening and/or firing. For the setup you described, [Aokatec AK-TTL](http://www.aokatec.com/AK-TTL.html) is to my knowledge the only radio trigger designed to work with (and even depend on) the control signals fired by built-in pop-up flash.